# constructor identifier not working for three objects

Tags: java, object, constructor, compare, equals

In this code, I take in two objects because I want to compare three different objects with each other (1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3) for some reason it will not recognise that objects 2 and 3 are equal.

```
    public boolean equals(Person num1, Person num2) {
    if ((this.name.equals(num1.name))&&(this.address.equals(num1.address))&&
    (this.age==num1.age)&&(this.phoneNumber==num1.phoneNumber))
        return true;
    if ((this.name.equals(num2.name))&&(this.address.equals(num2.address))&&
    (this.age==num2.age)&&(this.phoneNumber==num2.phoneNumber))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

demo class below

```
public class PersonDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //num1, num2, and num3 represent three people
    Person num1, num2, num3;
    num1=new Person("Allison", "6600 Crescent Ave", 32, 4231421);
    num2=new Person("George", "5251 Lakewood St", 24, 4489216);
    num3=new Person("George", "5251 Lakewood St", 24, 4489216);

    //name, address, age and phoneNumber are the parameters used to
    //describe each object (num1, num2, and num3)

    System.out.println("\nInformation of person 1: ");
    System.out.println(num1);

    System.out.println("\nInformation of person 2: ");
    System.out.println(num2);

    System.out.println("\nInformation of person 3: ");
    System.out.println(num3);

    if (num1.equals(num2))
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 2 are identical.");
    else 
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 2 are not identical.");
    if (num1.equals(num3))
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 3 are identical.");
    else 
        System.out.println("\nPerson 1 and person 3 are not identical.");
    if (num2.equals(num3))
        System.out.println("\nPerson 2 and person 3 are identical.");
    else 
        System.out.println("\nPerson 2 and person 3 are not identical.");
}
```

}
Output:
--------------------Configuration: --------------------

Information of person 1: 
Name: Allison
Address: 6600 Crescent Ave
Age: 32
Phone Number: 4231421

Information of person 2: 
Name: George
Address: 5251 Lakewood St
Age: 24
Phone Number: 4489216

Information of person 3: 
Name: George
Address: 5251 Lakewood St
Age: 24
Phone Number: 4489216

Person 1 and person 2 are not identical.

Person 1 and person 3 are not identical.

Person 2 and person 3 are not identical.

Process completed.

Comment: not a duplicate, as you can see I added "" marks, this is a different problem

Comment: Basically, I'm confused as to way it doesn't recognise 2 and 3 as objects with the same parameters.

Comment: @Nambari It's not a duplicate. OP got different errors.

Comment: Gucci you need to go through a  good starter tutorial or a book....

Comment: @user2503916 Of course it compiles, but it will be **Overloading** instead of **Overriding**.

Comment: `public boolean equals(Person num1, Person num2)` is not overloading anything... It has two parameters... My initial take was of overloading as well though...

Comment: @Thihara Doesn't it overload `public boolean equals(Object obj)`?

Comment: It will overload if the method was something like `boolean equals(Person num1)` His method has two parameter of type `Person` so it's not method overloading. Well at least as far as I know. Correct me if I'm wrong though... :-/

Comment: @johnchen902 Ah dude I didn't mean general overloading... I'm sorry if you got that idea, what I meant was that equals won't be called mistakenly because there are two method arguments in the signature there. In your meaning because of the name it's overloading but there's no place for a erroneous invocation because of the parameter number....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to overrides the [`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
public boolean equals(Person num1, Person num2) {
    // ...
}
```

However your signature is different. It should be:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Person))
        return false;
    Person num1 = (Person) o;
    if ((this.name.equals(num1.name))&&(this.address.equals(num1.address))&&
            (this.age==num1.age)&&(this.phoneNumber==num1.phoneNumber))
        return true;
}
```

1. If you want to override `Object.equals`, you must have exactly one argument whose type is an `Object`.
2. Use `@Override` to ensure your method really overrides something.

Comment: is there any simpler method for baby programmers like myself?

Comment: somehow it works if I just delete the other class coding in my class file

Comment: The other method is called learning the basics before coding.... This is basic method signatures.... You are creating a method with two parameters and calling a method with one parameter....